# How to search innerHTML of a button to what state or type is displayed? (innerHTML.indexOf)

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, indexof

On a website I have a button that is either "Log in" or "Log out" shown below

```
<button id="userLogBtn" class="user-log-in-log-out-2" data-wf-user-logout="Log out" data-wf-user-login="Log in" type="button">Log out</button>
```

The type="button" is either `>Log out<` or `>Log in<`.

How do I read the HTML to see **if** it is Log out

So far using something like this is not working

```
if (document.getElementById('userLogBtn').innerHTML.indexOf(">Log in<") = -1)
```

Comment: Using the text content of an element to determine behavior is a bad idea. Give the button a class value to indicate its state. That will be independent of the choice of wording for the text, and will work even if you translate the content to another language.

Comment: It maybe that your HTML doesn't parse in the state it's in. Use entities for the arrows: `&gt;Log out&lt;` for example.

Comment: 1. `=` is for **assignment**, setting the value of something. You should be getting an error for the assignment shown, since you can't assign to the result of a function call. If you used `==` or `===`, the the condition would be true if the button **did not** have the text `">Log in<"` in it.  2. And indeed, it won't, because it looks like your button's text is `"Log in"` (no `><`) or `"Log out"`.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking equality of `textContent` instead of the `innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById('userLogBtn').textContent === "Log in"
```

`innerHTML` represents the things *inside* the tag, between the `>` and `<`, so they won't show up in the returned string. `textContent` returns and `innerHTML` will be the same in this case (the real fix is `=== "Log in"`), but `textContent` returns only the text, which is what you want. `innerHTML` also returns the HTML of any elements inside the button (which there shouldn't be).

Comment: In your rush to be the first to answer your first edit was terrible, and would not have worked, and that's what I downvoted. Maybe be a little more patient in answering next time.